# How do i replace the currently open FMDB database retaining the current queue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, fmdb

I have a question regarding an app which stores its data in SQLite. The data is read using **FMDB** wrapper, and must be updated transparently to the user if the server side database changes.

To accomplish this, I'm replacing the entire `FMDatabase` object in my singleton with a new one whenever a new database is downloaded.

However, for a split second queries will fail, for example if the user is currently scrolling a table view.

So the question is, how do I replace the currently open `.sqlite` file while retaining the current queue?

Edit: Queries are run against the database very often, for example when scrolling a view there are count()s so there is no easy way to "block" the user from interacting with the database for a moment.

Comment: Are you using `FMDatabaseQueue`?  Or are you managing the queue yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be okay to add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` during that split second while the DB is updating? You could turn it on when the transfer begins and turn it off on a callback.

Comment: Not really - since the change could occur while say a tableview is decelerating after a swipe. Rows appearing while the database is unmounted will have blank detail text as that is only fetched when the row appears.

Comment: Any combination, its a database of exam questions and it could change in many ways.

Comment: Well that makes the situation a bit complicated, how about we listen for the end of deceleration, after the user swipes because then the user can only see what is currently in the database and then update before the user can swipe again?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you would be storing the datasource from the SQLite database in an array or some other collection, right?

So, whenever you finish downloading your updated database from the server, post a notification that "DatabaseUpdated". (This code should be in your Shared Singleton).

And, make your view controller an observer for this notification.

On receiving this notification, just call `[tableView reloadData];` in your view controller.

So, in effect, your view will be updated as per your new database changes.

Comment: While this is a good idea, it is not viable in my situation since the detail row of each cell does a count() which i only want to execute when the row is visible. I don't want to do thousands of potentially unnecessary count()'s before displaying the list (to cache the data from the sqlite). This would defeat the purpose of a databse.

Comment: I didn't know about the `count()` that is being used in your case. So, this won't suffice.